# Edges Look Uneven

Tags: edges

I've been searching for and answer but can't seem to find one. i'm not 100% on how to explain but i have attached a image.

The edges on my model don't look straight they seem to zig zag there way up. is there a way to make it completely straight? i am only new to blender.

Thanks in advanced.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The resolution of the screen isn't accurate enough. As a screen is divided into pixels, and you can't colour a fraction of a pixel differently than the rest of it, at some places there will be such bumps when the view angle is not aligned with the line. Think of it on a larger scale. Try for example to make a diagonal line on graph paper, by colouring only complete squares. The length of each segment will depend on the angle. It looks the same on my screen.

[image]

And, as you can see here, it's a lot less visible when rendered out, due to shading techniques used by the renderer.

[image]